# Are there any good flat file to object mapping library for C# / .Net?

Tags: c#, .net, orm, mapping, flat-file

i've been searching around and was wondering are there any good libraries especially in c# or .net which are made specifically for mapping flat file?

so far the only one i found is [canyon](http://sourceforge.net/projects/canyons/).

thanks

Comment: Take a look at [FileHelpers](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: wow, think that's useful, will give it a go. thanks

Comment: @JayRiggs You should give that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following link specifies the Altova MapForce tool for procesing flat files
http://www.altova.com/mapforce/flat-file-mapping.html

The following link specifies flat file verification using c# :
http://blog.flat-file.net/2011/12/flat-file-checker-validation-using-cnet.html

Hope this helps. Thanks.